# mysql syntax error - date_format

Tags: php, mysql, syntax-error, date-format

I am trying to format a datetime field in php, but i get this error code:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that  
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax  
to use near 'DATE_FORMAT(date, '%b %d
```

This is my whole code:

```
SELECT * FROM topics, DATE_FORMAT(date, '%b %d %Y, %h:%i %p') AS f_date
```

I've checked everything, this is usually how I do my formatting, compared the code to other formattings ive done.
Any help with what's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(date, '%b %d %Y, %h:%i %p') AS f_date FROM topics`

Comment: Ah, of course it's the little things! Accepting as soon as I can.

Answer (score 2):

You can't select all (*) and then add columns with that syntax. It can be done like this:

```
SELECT topics.*, DATE_FORMAT(date, '%b %d %Y, %h:%i %p') AS f_date FROM topics
```

Edit: as @Vyacheslav Voronchuk points out, you can use just `*` instead of `topics.*` if you only query a single table.

Comment: He can, you can try it live on your MySQL. `topics.*` is required only if he uses more than one table in his `SELECT`.

Comment: Why the downvote? @VyacheslavVoronchuk no actually you can't add columns after the FROM clause, which is what OP was trying to do. That's what my answer refers to.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your answer, thought you were pointing that table reference (topics.*) is required to add additional columns in response. Will remove down-vote when I can.

Comment: @VyacheslavVoronchuk edited with your point about the topics.*, cheers